# How to make a LazyColumn with a nested LazyRow, which switches the next element when clicked, the column scrolls vertically as usual?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I want to make a feed with photos (glide) and videos (ExoPlayer media3), each post will have up to 20 attachments, which should be switched only by click (I want to use lazy row for optimization, because the task is such that the photo when switching quickly ,should be like a slide show)"

```
     
    @Composable
    fun HomeScreen(
        navController: NavController,
        navControllerMain: NavController
    ) {
        val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
        val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp
    
        val feedViewModel = FeedViewModel()
        val listOfSenses by feedViewModel.listOfSenses.observeAsState(emptyList())
        val currentSense by feedViewModel.currentSense.observeAsState(null)
        val currentAttachmentIndex by feedViewModel.currentAttachmentIndex.observeAsState()
    
    
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()
        val rowState = rememberLazyListState()
    
    
     LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(listOfSenses) { index, sense ->
                LazyRow(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    state = rowState
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(sense.Attachments) { indexAttachment, attachment ->
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .background(Color.Blue)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                        ) {
                            PostCard(
                                    attachment = attachment,
                                    screenHeight = screenHeight,
                                    screenWidth = screenWidth,
                                    viewModel = feedViewModel,
                                    sense = sense
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

ExoPlayer intercepts clicks, it is not possible to place them on composable elements, the toast only works here:

```
    @Composable
    @androidx.annotation.OptIn(androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi::class)
    fun VideoPlayer(
        screenHeight: Dp,
        screenWidth: Dp,
        attachment: MediaAttachment,
        viewModel: FeedViewModel
        ) {
        val uri = Uri.parse("https://senses.team/${attachment.Video}")
        val context = LocalContext.current
    
        val exoPlayer = remember {
            ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                .build()
                .apply {
                    val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
                    val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
                        context,
                        defaultDataSourceFactory
                    )
                    val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
    
                    setMediaSource(source)
                    prepare()
                }
        }
    
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
        exoPlayer.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
    
        DisposableEffect(
            AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(screenHeight)
                    .width(screenWidth)
                    .background(Color.Black),
                factory = {
                PlayerView(context).apply {
                    hideController()
                    useController = false
                    resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT
                    player = exoPlayer
                    layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
                    setOnClickListener {
                        viewModel.onScreenTap()
                     Toast.makeText(context, viewModel.currentAttachmentIndex.value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            })
        ) {
            onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
        }
    }
```

I want to use ViewModel to connect the player with the view feed:

```
    
    
    class FeedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
        private val _listOfSenses = MutableLiveData<List<Sense>>(ListOfSenses)
        val listOfSenses: LiveData<List<Sense>> = _listOfSenses
    
        private val _currentSense = MutableLiveData<Sense>()
        val currentSense: LiveData<Sense> = _currentSense
    
        private val _currentAttachmentIndex = MutableLiveData(0)
        val currentAttachmentIndex: LiveData<Int> = _currentAttachmentIndex
    
        fun setCurrentSense(sense: Sense) {
            _currentSense.value = sense
        }
    
        fun incAttachmentIndex() {
            val currentSense = _currentSense.value
            val currentAttachmentIndex = _currentAttachmentIndex.value
            currentSense?.let { sense ->
                val attachmentsSize = sense.Attachments?.size ?: 0
                if (attachmentsSize > 0) {
                    val updatedAttachmentIndex = currentAttachmentIndex?.inc()?.rem(attachmentsSize)
                    _currentAttachmentIndex.value = updatedAttachmentIndex
                }
            }
        }
    
        fun onPlayVideoClick() {
        }
    
        fun onScreenTap() {
            incAttachmentIndex()
        }
    }
```

I tried to attach a click handler to different elements of the view, but I couldn’t figure out how to scroll the row to the desired element when changing the data in the view model, I couldn’t remove the possibility of regular scrolling from the row
the only thing I could achieve was that toast comes out when you click on the element
I tried to change the row state using scrollToItem() in a coroutine that monitors the state of the currentAttachmentIndex variable